# php mysqli_multi_query not getting data

Tags: php, autocomplete, mysqli-multi-query, multi-query

I try results from db for autocomplete search.
I use this code for getting names,
in db I have a row with four columns that can contain the searched keyword.

```
function search_results($conn,$str){

$sql = "SELECT g_custom_1 as str FROM gallery WHERE  g_custom_1 LIKE '%{$str}%'";
$sql .= "SELECT g_custom_2 as str FROM gallery WHERE  g_custom_2 LIKE '%{$str}%'";
$sql .= "SELECT g_custom_3 as str FROM gallery WHERE  g_custom_3 LIKE '%{$str}%'";
$sql .= "SELECT g_custom_4 as str FROM gallery WHERE  g_custom_4 LIKE '%{$str}%'";


//$sub_data=array();
if (mysqli_multi_query($conn,$sql))
{
    $data=array();
    do
    {
        // Store first result set
        if ($result=mysqli_store_result($conn)) {
        // Fetch one and one row
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
        {
            $data[]=$row['str'];
        }
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
    }
    while (mysqli_next_result($conn));
}
else{
    echo "error";
}
$data_unique=array_unique($data);
return $data_unique;
   }
```

Comment: what output or error you got?

Comment: You get a wrong query during on concat. You can get the same result with one SELECT query.

Comment: error
Warning: array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in functions.php on line 41

Comment: Taron how i do this?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting result in `$row['str'];`?

Comment: i dont't now, becouse this not entering to if

Comment: Write `print_r(mysqli_multi_query($conn,$sql))` before `if` statement. Tell me what you got

Comment: nothing show print

Comment: It should print 1 then `if` will execute. Make sure you had mysql connection in `$conn`

Comment: in one function call you are creating $sql variable , with concatination of multiple qureis and the genrated query in $sql variable is wrong, please correct yur query first. you can match multiple columns using 'OR' opreator .

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate each query using a semicolon.  Here is your current string:

```
$sql="SELECT g_custom_1 as str FROM gallery WHERE  g_custom_1 LIKE '%{$str}%'SELECT g_custom_2 as str FROM gallery WHERE  g_custom_2 LIKE '%{$str}%'SELECT g_custom_3 as str FROM gallery WHERE  g_custom_3 LIKE '%{$str}%'SELECT g_custom_4 as str FROM gallery WHERE  g_custom_4 LIKE '%{$str}%'";
```

Notice how the SELECT in the subsequent queries are smashed into the rear end of the previous query?

I might suggest:

```
$sql[]="SELECT g_custom_1 as str FROM gallery WHERE  g_custom_1 LIKE '%{$str}%'";
$sql[]="SELECT g_custom_2 as str FROM gallery WHERE  g_custom_2 LIKE '%{$str}%'";
$sql[]="SELECT g_custom_3 as str FROM gallery WHERE  g_custom_3 LIKE '%{$str}%'";
$sql[]="SELECT g_custom_4 as str FROM gallery WHERE  g_custom_4 LIKE '%{$str}%'";
if(mysqli_multi_query($conn,implode(';',$sql))){
```

You might also find this answer informative: [Strict Standards: mysqli_next_result() error with mysqli_multi_query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715889/strict-standards-mysqli-next-result-error-with-mysqli-multi-query/22469722#22469722)