# MYSQL query works in PHPMyAdmin but not on website

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to move all data from one table to another and that bit on it's own works fine, the part I am having trouble with is then deleting the data from the old table. The MYSQL query I hvae put together runs fine as an SQL query on PHPMyAdmin but for some reason gives me an error about syntax at line 2 if i run it from my webpage. Please see below for the query from the website.

```
if($old == 'Yesterday'){
$movequery = "INSERT INTO yesthistory select * from history; 
TRUNCATE TABLE history";

if (!mysqli_query($con2, $movequery))
{
    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con2));
}
```

Comment: `mysqli_query()` can only preform one query at a time. You're doing two `INSERT` and `TURNICATE`.

Comment: You can create a `TRIGGER` or use `mysqli_multi_query` or loop the queries.  Food for thought: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715889/strict-standards-mysqli-next-result-error-with-mysqli-multi-query/22469722#22469722

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of you are performing 2 operations seperated by semiclon in a single query
 **query should be this**

```
$movequery1 = "INSERT INTO yesthistory select * from history";
$movequery2 = "TRUNCATE TABLE history";
```

then run these queries one by one.

Answer (score 0):

use the [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-overview.html) to run a job every day, based on the `WHERE` clause in your statement:

```
CREATE EVENT archive_history 
   ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
   COMMENT 'archives claims older than their expiry date'
DO 
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO yesthishistory SELECT * FROM history WHERE ....
   DELETE FROM history WHERE ....
END
```

If it only runs once per day (because you don't have any finer time resolution in your expiry logic), you won't have massive performance slow-down every time you run a modification.