# How to get json_encode data of php url using jquery ajax ?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

autocomplete-api.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    error_reporting(0);
    include("includes/config.php");

    $data = array();
    $query = "SELECT product_name FROM inventory group by product_name;";
    $query .= "SELECT name FROM brands;";
    $query .= "SELECT name FROM categories;";

    mysqli_multi_query($con,$query);
    $result = mysqli_store_result($con);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $data[] = array(
                        'products' => $row['product_name']
                    );
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_next_result($con);

    $result = mysqli_store_result($con);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = array(
                        'products' => $row['name']
                    );
    } 

    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_next_result($con);

    $result = mysqli_store_result($con);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = array(
                        'products' => $row['name']
                    );
    } 

    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($con);

    $results = json_encode($data);
    print($results);
?>
```

autocomplete.js

```
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  var currentFocus;
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        currentFocus++;
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        currentFocus--;
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    if (!x) return false;
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
      });
}
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"http://localhost/leafteaculture/autocomplete-api.php",
    datatype:"JSON",
    success:function(json){
        alert(json);
        /*$.each(json, function(key, item) {
            var countries =  item.products;
            alert(countries);
        });*/
    }
});
```

Index.php

```
<input type="text" name="pro_duct" id="pro_duct" />

<script src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>assets/js/autocomplete.js"></script>
<script>
    autocomplete(document.getElementById("pro_duct"), countries);
</script>
```

Possible might be duplicate question. I have created autocomplete suggestion box where I have `autocomplete-api.php` where I have used `json_encode` function which is working fine but problem with `autocomplete.js` file. I am unable to get data from `autocomplete-api.php` file. I want to fetch data from `autocompelete-api.php` url and put it into the jquery variable. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: I've never used `print` when sending JSON data from PHP to an AJAX call. I've always used `echo`. In the several examples I've googled, I don't find one that uses `print`. The two are supposed to be pretty much the same (`print` returns a value and only allows one argument; `echo` doesn't return a value and uses multiple arguments, and they both call the same function under the hood), but you might try using `echo` instead of `print` the way everyone else does.

Comment: Here is some more concise syntax for your multi query: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22469722/2943403  Better still, you should write a single query with two `UNION`s and alias the the first column of the first query `products`.

Comment: Edit: nope, I've tested it, and print works the same as echo. Since you don't need the value that print returns, maybe that's why everyone uses echo.

Answer (score 0):

The possible problem might be that since you've used `json_encode` which returns a `string` and in the AJAX request you've specified the `dataType` to be `JSON`, AJAX is unable to find the required dataType in the response. You could simply remove the dataType property from the AJAX request. Once the data is fetched, you need to use `JSON.parse` to convert the string to JSON format.

Refer to [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation and [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for more info.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing to fix is your php file -- let's boil that thing down.
You can maintain the same query logic / resulset with much less hassle by using `UNION` keywords to form a single / more efficient query.

```
session_start();
header('Content-type: application/json');
include("includes/config.php");

if (!$result = $con->query("(SELECT product_name AS products FROM inventory GROUP BY product_name) UNION (SELECT name FROM brands) UNION (SELECT name FROM categories)")) {
    echo [];  // check $con->error; because your query failed
} else {
    echo json_encode($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
}
```

Yes, it really can be reduced THAT much!  Here's [proof that the query works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf9ae5/1).

From the same data, here is the generated json string:

```
[{"products":"One"},{"products":"Three"},{"products":"Two"},{"products":"Four"},{"products":"Five"},{"products":"Six"},{"products":"Seven"},{"products":"Eight"}]
```

Then, then the json string is received by your javascript, call `var apiArray = = JSON.parse(json);` so that you can work with the multi-dimensional array containing a single column of data.

---

...p.s. If you are worried about duplicate product names, you can weed out duplicates in the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product FROM (
    (SELECT product_name AS product FROM inventory GROUP BY product_name)
    UNION
    (SELECT name FROM brands)
    UNION
    (SELECT name FROM categories)
) Unionized
```

Comment: @omkara If this does not eliminate your issue.  Please update your question to express what IS working as expected, what isn't, and any server-side and client-side errors.