# php mysql multiquery does not return result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to execute the following.

```
public function result_multi($sql) {

    try {
        mysqli_multi_query($this->db_connection,$sql);
        $result=mysqli_store_result($this->db_connection);
        $row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    }

$b=new DB;
$sql="INSERT INTO payout (mid, type, datetime) VALUES ('0','BC', 
NOW());SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();";
$b->result_multi($sql);
```

$row returns NULL and $result return FALSE, however when I execute the SQL query in phpmyadmin it works.

Comment: Your code looks invalid.  I don't think you can have a try block without a catch and/or finally block (what would be the point?)

Comment: Here's a comprehensive post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22469722/2943403 but honestly why not only INSERT then use php to grab the last id?  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to fetching the results of a multi query, [the `mysqli_multi_query` documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) states :

> To retrieve the resultset from the first query you can use `mysqli_use_result()` or `mysqli_store_result()`. All subsequent query results can be processed using `mysqli_more_results()` and `mysqli_next_result()`.

So you would need to call `mysqli_next_result` once to access the results of the second query, and then `mysqli_store_result/mysqli_fetch_row` to fetch the id.

But in your use case, it seems like a simpler way to proceed is to use `mysqli_insert_id` method, like :

```
my $conn = $this->db_connection;
$sql = "INSERT INTO payout (mid, type, datetime) VALUES ('0','BC', NOW())";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    echo "Record inserted with ID " . $last_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

PS : you should also check for errors after opening the connection to the database.

Comment: this worked but why would the sql option not work.

Comment: @the_big_blackbox : I updated my answer with explanations

Comment: thanks both solutions now work

Comment: is there any advantage / disadvantage to either approach?

Comment: I would recommend using `mysqli_insert_id`, because it is specifically designed for this use case. `mysqli_multi_query` better fits the cases when random multiple SQL need to be executed.

Answer (score -2):

I need more code for this, because you used the multi sql so must have more query.

Try this code if only one query sql :

```
public function result($sql) {

    try {
        mysqli_query($this->db_connection,$sql);
        $result=mysqli_store_result($this->db_connection);
        $row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    }

$b=new DB;
$sql="INSERT INTO payout (mid, type, datetime) VALUES ('0','BC', 
NOW());SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();";
$b->result($sql);
```

Comment: What did you change? Why does your code still contain syntax errors?

Comment: Where the error ? could you proof it ?

Comment: Well, where is this function `result` contained in? Probably within the DB class which you initialize within that function?

Comment: $b->result($sql); thats the db, we can't test because don't see the real code.

Comment: and where your solution ? I give the solution with delete multi query....are you spam in comment ?